# Oracle Entity Relationship diagramming tool

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-modeling

Does anyone know a good opensource tool that can be used to manage Entities in Oracle 11G? For Mysql we have workbench even-though it has some bugs it's getting better. As for Oracle I couldn't find a tool for modeling data. I hope someone could lead me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle's Data Modeler is not open source, but it's free:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html

Comment: @Duli-chan: why shouldn't it?

Comment: If it does... Then it's ok...Since most of the tools are for Oracle 10G

Comment: 10g is no longer fully supported (10.1 is out of support anyway and for 10.2 you only get extended support). Only 11g is has full (=regular) support from Oracle.